# How can I "merge" two HTML tags via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, merge, tags

Here is my HTML "sandbox":

```
<p>1 2 3</p>
<span id="myid">
<span id="mytext">
<p>4 5 6</p>
<p>7 8 9</p>
<p>10 11 12</p>
</span>
</span>
<p>13 14 15</p>
```

I would like to "merge" the p tags accordingly:
*(To make it easier to see I've added a **minus sign** where I've made the changes:)*

```
<p>1 2 3 -
<span id="myid">
<span id="mytext">
- 4 5 6</p>
<p>7 8 9</p>
<p>10 11 12 -
</span>
</span>
- 13 14 15</p>
```

Every place I've added a minus sign, I have actually stripped a `<p>` or `</p>` tag making a merge between the two paragraph elements ( between 1 2 3 and 4 5 6 & between 10 11 12 and 13 14  15) - (**This merge is only to achieve a display inline for 123-456 & 101112-131415**).

**How can I achieve this result with 'raw' JavaScript (not libraries please).**

Note:
*I've tried to create something but It took me 80 lines of code - I am sure there is a better way of doing this.*

**Edit:**
Jon Hanna mentioned in his comment I could use correct HTML like so (as the result of JavaScript):

```
    <p>1 2 3 <span class="myclass mytext">4 5 6</span></p>
<p class="myclass mytext">7 8 9</p>
<p><span class="myclass mytext"10 11 12</span> 13 14 15</p>
```

Comment: Your `<span>`s would be invalidly nested; they would open and close across different `<p>`s... If that's a typo, please correct it so we know what you mean.

Comment: @PPvG, it is meant to be like that. (I know it isn't valid html but I just need to to function like I demonstrated)

Comment: Then it's invalid HTML, which causes browsers to react unpredictably. This will make JavaScript difficult to apply, it will likely react unreliably.

Comment: @DavidThomas, Like said to #@PPvG I know it isn't correct html, but I need it to be structured like that.

Comment: Strictly speaking even the HTML in the first example, because it nests block-level elements (the `p`s) inside inline-level elements (the `span`s). But anyway; if your HTML is not validly structured, your browser can never build a correct representation of it in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_W3C_DOM_Level_1_Core). And that makes it **really** hard to manipulate using JavaScript.

Comment: Are you not able to correct your HTML in order to make it valid?

Comment: @DavidThomas, no, that is why I am asking for ideas.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense you'd wanted like that... What is the purpose of working in JS with clearly invalid HTML code? Is not just that it's invalid but wrong.

Comment: You just can't structure it like that, if the second chunk is supposed to be your output. What possible usecase calls for completely invalid HTML?

Comment: @elclanrs, look I didn't ask for html QA, I just wanted to know if this could be manipulated to get to that result in a "simple" way (less than 80 lines of code). this is the situation like I stated above, and I need to work with it.

Comment: @agam360 But you *can't* work with it once you have it like that. Nothing will parse it correctly, you won't be able to *do* anything with it in a deterministic fashion.

Comment: Can you tell us what the two `<span>`s do? What is the function of `myid` and `mytext`? Perhaps we can help you rethink your HTML so your problem can be solved.

Comment: I'm just curious to know why you'd want to keep it that way and assume all the problems that will arise, rather than reorganizing the code? I mean , there must be a good reason for this that I'm not thinking of...

Comment: Ok, as Jon Hanna mentioned in his comment I could use correct HTML (see my edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Bear with me, I started writing this before your latest edit. I think it's still useful, though.)*

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but I can tell you that it's **very** hard to achieve *exactly* what you're asking for using JavaScript. This is mostly because the HTML would be invalid.

Let's first walk through **why** the HTML would be invalid. When the browser parses HTML, it builds a nested **tree** of DOM Nodes. Your first example could be represented like this:

- `<p>`

  - 1 2 3
- `<span id="myid">`

  - `<span id="mytext">`

    - `<p>`

      - 4 5 6
    - `<p>`

      - 7 8 9
    - `<p>`

      - 10 11 12
- `<p>`

  - 13 14 15

Using JavaScript and the DOM, you can walk through this tree and manipulate it. You could combine the text node from various `<p>` tags and place them in a single `<p>` tag without problem. But you won't be able to create the structure of your second example. It's simply not shaped like a DOM tree, so you can't use the DOM to create that HTML.

The only way manipulate the HTML into the shape of your second example is through `innerHTML`,  like [Jon Hanna explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014219/990877). The good news is that browsers will **always** correct invalid HTML into a valid DOM structure. The bad news is that each browser does this differently, so you never know what you end up with.

The only real solution is to rethink your HTML structure, like you've done in your latest edit.

The way to solve your original problem depends on how static your original HTML is. I'll give a crude example, for which I'll presume that:

- there's always exactly **5** `<p>`'s
- the second through fourth of the `<p>`'s are always inside the `<span>`'s, and the first and fifth always outside them

If those two conditions are met, you could use something like this:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var newParagraphs = [];

function createElementWithText(tagname, text, classname) {
    var classname = classname || '';
    var element = document.createElement(tagname);
    element.className = classname;
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return element;
}

newParagraphs[0] = createElementWithText('p', paragraphs[0].textContent);
newParagraphs[0].appendChild(createElementWithText('span', paragraphs[1].textContent, 'myclass mytext'));

newParagraphs[1] = createElementWithText('p', paragraphs[2].textContent, 'myclass mytext');

newParagraphs[2] = document.createElement('p');
newParagraphs[2].appendChild(createElementWithText('span', paragraphs[3].textContent, 'myclass mytext'));
newParagraphs[2].appendChild(document.createTextNode(paragraphs[4].textContent));
```

I've posted a working example on JSFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/vSrLJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/vSrLJ/)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to think about something more appealing to the tree-like structure.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it with obtaining the source-code through `innerHTML` etc, manipulating the string and then outputting the string.

While the DOMs generally won't stop the fact that you incorrectly have `<p>` inside `<span>`, it's just not logically possible for them to represent the output you want, since there's no `HalfWrittenPElement` object.

Your requirement to deliberately break the rules is at odds with the object model being designed to help you, so hacking with strings is all you've got.

Edit:

Though that said, the browsers will all fix it in their internal model anyway, so it's still going to end up as well-formed (if not necessarily valid) HTML. It'll just be so according to implementation-defined corrections rather than any spec.

Comment: Ok, what If I only want to have 123-456 & 101112-131415 in the same line (aka: display:inline)? what should I do then?

Comment: Why not aim for output closer to `<p>1 2 3 <span class="myclass mytext">4 5 6</span></p><p class="myclass mytext">7 8 9</p><p><span class="myclass mytext"10 11 12</span> 13 14 15</p>`. Lines as you want, inner block associated with `myclass` and `mytext`, well-formed, valid, and understandable?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you'll get the idea. You can do the debugging and crossbrowser fine-tuning yourself ;)

I'll find all the `<p>` tags and for each of them, check if its siblings are `<span>`, `<span>` and `<p>`. Then I'll put the `<span>`s and the text of the second `<p>` inside the first `<p>`.

```
var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');  // get all <p>

for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {         // for every one of them
   var a = pTags[i];                             // take the <p> (and call it `a`)

   var b = a.nextElementSibling();               // and the next tag (call it `b`)
   if (b == null) continue;

   var c = b.nextElementSibling();               // and the next tag (call it `c`)
   if (c == null) continue;

   var d = c.nextElementSibling();               // and the next tag (call it `d`)
   if (d == null) continue;

   if (b.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'SPAN' &&      //  if b is <span>
       c.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'SPAN' &&      // and c is <span>
       d.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'P') {         // and d is <p> again

         a.appendChild(b);                       // put b inside a
         a.appendChild(c);                       // put c inside a
         a.appendChild(d.firstChild.nodeValue);  // put text of d inside a
   }
}
```

Note that `nextElementSibling` method is not cross-browser, but you can emulate it by calling `nextSibling` until it is of the `Element` type.

Note also that by calling `appendChild` the element first gets removed from its original container, and only then it is appended. Which is what we want.

**Quick edit:**

As others have pointed out, you have invalid html, what I didn't notice at first. But I suppose you wanted to have the `<span>`s properly closed.

Comment: Calling appendChild means you'll end up with at least well-formed HTML, which isn't wanted.

Comment: Though I realise mine will end up with a well-formed output in the rendering step anyway, now I think of it.