# Merge equal element DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, rich-text-editor

Hello I am a JavaScript developer, I'm trying to create a text editor working on the DOM. 
I was able to implement, given the complexity, a good algorithm to wrap and unwrap the elements but now I find myself in some cases to have a dom like this:

```
<p>
   a
   <strong>b</strong>
   <strong>c</strong>
   <strong>d</strong>
</p>
```

and

```
<strong>
    <strong>hello world</strong>
</strong>
```

I would get a structure like this:

```
<p>
  a
  <strong>
    bcd
  </strong> 
</p>
```

and

```
<strong>hello world</strong>
```

So the question is: How can I get a dom "normalized", a combining tags adjacent? I would need a generalized technique that can be applied to my dom after changes have been made with the editor.
Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: But there are whitespaces between `b`, `c` and `d`?

Comment: Yep, there may be whitespaces between elements. Anywere we have to do this with the dom, without a string parse algorithm

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything yet? A simple recursive algorithm should be able to do it.

Comment: Btw, which tags are supposed to be merged? I'd guess you don't want to join two subsequent `<p>` tags?

Comment: I need to combine all these element : span, strong, em, u

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014138/how-can-i-merge-two-html-tags-via-javascript

Comment: I had already seen this thread, but unfortunately I was not help. Thanks anyway. My problem is that I can not understand all the conditions that I have to deal with recursive cycle when the dom.